# VBScript: how to write an event-driven script for checking if network cable has been unplugged?

Tags: events, vbscript

I manage a lab with computers running Win XP Pro SP3. For a lot of reasons it is important that the network cable is always plugged in. Unfortunately some guys like to unplug the network cable: in this scenario when network cable is unplugged a shutdown command starts as a punishment for having unplugged it. At the moment I accomplish this using a VBS script starting when user logs in that acts like an infinite loop like this:

Do

WMI code for checking network status...

Loop

But in this case script is alway running and uses a lot of cpu pertentage. Now, it is possible in VBS to write a script that is able to "listen" an event like the disconnection?
Please don't advice to change programming language.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do they unplug before or after logging in?, if it's before you can use a MSHTA to load a full screen warning via the startup of the default profile on the machine that is used to build temporary profiles when the network is unavailable, unless local profiles are used. Used to work really well for a hospital trust I worked for where people would come in with laptops swapping cables leaving desktops unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of CPU because you're constantly checking the status while this is not actually necessary - just put a sleep in your loop and set it to like 10 seconds.

Either way this is a very bizarre way of approaching the problem - why not just talk with your workers instead? Maybe there's a legitimate reason why they're unplugging the network?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can't use the sleep command because the action must be immediate when users unplug network cables. I don't know eglish so well for exlpaining why users have interest to unplug network cables also for few secs and why we have interest for punishing them with a reboot immediately. So I need something acting as a event-driven script. Have a nice day.